# XmlDocument Load vs. LoadXml with Right Quote

Tags: .net, xml

I am seeing a difference between the way XmlDocument Load( ) and LoadXml( ) work in .NET 2.0.  Given the XML document below (note the use of a right quote, ascii code 146):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<nodes>
  <node>Some Data ’</node>
</nodes>
```

Why does it load fine with LoadXml( ) when passed in as a string but fails if passed in to Load( ) as a document.  I.E. and other XML editors also will not load and display this file.

Simplified Code Example:

```
[WebMethod]
public bool SubmitData(string xmlDoc)
{
   try
   {
      XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
      doc.LoadXml(xmlDoc);
   }
   catch
   {
      return false;
   }

   return true;
}
```

I know the code is poor but it is just meant to demonstrate the problem.  If the string "xmlDoc" is not a legitimate xml document, then I am trying to get this to fail.

I can't control the content of the XML sent to me.  I just receive it and work with it through the web service.  Apparently, the people calling it are copying and pasting data from a Word Doc.  I didn't design this either but I am stuck maintaining it. :)

Comment: Sounds like an [encoding issue](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html) or an escapement issue.

Comment: Please show the code you're using and the _complete_ exception you receive when it doesn't work.

Comment: Actually ASCII is seven bits (max. 128) so 146 cannot be the characters ASCII value. It is the value on 8-bit encodings. In Unicode its code is U+2019. This alone suggests that you have not saved your document in UTF-8, yet the prolog claims so. This results in invalid characters which results in malformed XML.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The difference is the encoding. When loading from a file, utf-8 decoding is applied and your code 146 is probably not valid utf-8 in your case. LoadXml ignores the encoding because .Net strings do not need to be decoded. Therfore your special character is a valid character and everything is fine.

Comment: Is there a way for me to enforce encoding when using LoadXml?  Or validate it against the encoding after it has been loaded?  Thanks.

Comment: You have to understand the difference between a .Net string and raw binary data. The string does not have an encoding (from the users point of view) so your question makes no sense. There is nothing to validate if the documents has been loaded.

Comment: I understand your point and realize my question is worded badly.  My issue remains though that I am being sent an XML Document as a string in a web service and am being asked to check and enforce that string as though it was a raw document.  Any ideas on ways to do that?  Maybe it is not possible but I am not ready to give up yet.  Thanks again.

Comment: If you have some raw binary data, you can interpret it as ascii characters. Sometimes that kind of missused "strings" are send to web services. In that case you would have to convert the .Net string back to raw binary data. After that you would be able to read it as it would be a raw file. That is back practice in my opinion, but that opinion does not help you much. ;-) To help I would have to see much more details and know more about internals.

Answer (score 1):

In case anyone is interested, we found another way to "validate" the string to at least check for proper characters.  We had tried similar things before but didn't use the correct constructor on UTF8Encoding and hence, didn't get the results we hoped for.  This won't necessarily check for XML correctness, but it will at least validate the characters being sent to us.

```
string xmlDoc = ""; // whatever has been passed in.
try
{
   System.Text.UTF8Encoding utf8 = new System.Text.UTF8Encoding(false, true);
   byte[] bytes = new System.Text.UnicodeEncoding().GetBytes(xmlDoc);
   utf8.GetChars(bytes);
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
   Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
   return false;
}
```